# finding closest date (but not the same date) in R

Tags: r

To find the closest date, I have:

```
closestDate <- function(searchDate, dateList, roundDown=FALSE) {
              as.Date(sapply(as.Date(searchDate), function(x){
                dist <- abs(x - as.Date(dateList))
                closest <- dateList[which(min(dist) == dist)]
                return(ifelse(roundDown, min(closest), max(closest)))
              }), origin="1970-1-1")
            }
```

When:

```
> nonNAdays
[1] "2011-08-15" "2011-08-18" "2011-08-19"
```

I get:

```
> closestDate('2011-08-15', nonNAdays)
[1] "2011-08-15"
```

I would like for the function to give me the closest date other than the date itself. So in this case, "2011-08-18". How can I alter my code to get this?
Thanks.

Comment: EricaO, if you find your question answered, then please accept it as answered by ticking the checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the dates that *are* equal from the dist calculations and from the selection operation:

```
  closestDate <- function(searchDate, dateList, roundDown=FALSE) {
           as.Date(sapply(as.Date(searchDate), function(x){
             dist <- abs(x - as.Date(dateList[dateList != searchDate]))
             closest <- dateList[dateList != searchDate][which(min(dist) == dist)]
             return(ifelse(roundDown, min(closest), max(closest)))
           }), origin="1970-1-1")
         }
 nonNAdays <- c("2011-08-15", "2011-08-18", "2011-08-19")
  closestDate('2011-08-15', nonNAdays)
#[1] "2011-08-18"
```

Comment: Shouldn't `x` be `searchDate`?

Comment: With:
closestDate <- function(searchDate, dateList, roundDown=FALSE) {
               as.Date(sapply(as.Date(searchDate), function(x){
                 dist <- abs(x - as.Date(dateList[dateList != searchDate]))
                 closest <- dateList[which(min(dist) == dist)]
                 return(ifelse(roundDown, min(closest), max(closest)))
               }), origin="1970-1-1")
             }

Comment: I still get:> closestDate('2011-08-15', nonNAdays)
[1] "2011-08-15"

Comment: I'll post the entire code I'm using since I get the result uypu were expecting.